# Determine whether someone is hard-wired to router in C++

Tags: c++, qt

We are trying to come up with the best way to detect if a user is hard-wired to their router in a C++ program being developed in Qt.  It is okay if they are on WiFi also, but there needs to be a hard-wire present, as well.

This would only need to work on Windows but it would need to work on XP, Vista, 7, 8, and 8.1.

We tried the QNetworkConfiguration::BearerType which was promising but didn't seem to give any definitive results.

Has anyone ever done this or have an idea on how to?  What is the best way?  And if the answer involves QNetworkConfiguration, how do you figure it for the possibility that someone may be hard wired thru the Local Area Connection?

*EDIT FOR CLARITY*
We employ work-from-home sales agents that use a softphone to make calls.  We require them to be hard-wired to their router for better call quality.  Since they are work from home, it is very hard to keep them plugged in without constant monitoring.  They use a custom interface that we have control over and would like to be able to do this check before activating the interface, as well as periodically re-checking to ensure they stay plugged in.

Comment: To clarify; Are you trying to determine whether or not there is attached an ethernet cable to the machine, and in the other end of that same cable there is attached a router?

Comment: What is the problem that you are ACTUALLY trying to solve?

Comment: We employ work-from-home phone-sales agents that we require are hard-wired to their router for better SIP call quality.  They use a custom interface that we would like to have determine if that hard line is there before it is activated... and possibly continue to check while they use the program.

Comment: My computer at home has a hard-wired Ethernet cable going to the router, but my router's uplink connection is a wifi link to a second router on the other side of the house.  I don't think there's any way to detect that, since the wifi link is not visible to the computer.

Comment: Have you verified that the wireless is actually the problem? If they're on some cheap, highly oversubscribed connection, the actual problem might very well be the ISP. That kind of service may still have somewhat decent bandwidth even when the jitter has become horrible.

Comment: Ugh!! You guys are right.. there really is no way to know for sure.  We were even thinking of just disabling the WiFi while the program runs but we will still run into the same issues for people like Jeremy, where there is just no way to know for sure.

We can't always say that WiFi _is_ the problem but it often causes problems and it's been a good rule just to keep the problems minimized.  Our offshore agents typically need all the extra boost they can get so it's been a "requirement" even tho we haven't been able to enforce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. A computer could be connected through a chain of a dozen switches (or worse, hubs) or a mile of untwisted pair cabling and there is no way you could specifically check that through software.

What you can do instead is measure the quality of the connection (ping time to default gateway and/or some known good external host, packet loss to same, etc).

Comment: This is what I was afraid of.  We are currently pinging the server used by their softphone every 5 minutes (taking a 3-second average).  Maybe we can add a packet loss and jitter test, as well?  Thanks!  Would +1 but still too new :)

Comment: Any decent softphone program will measure packet loss and jitter anyway. Can't you get the data from there?

Comment: The softphone we use is embedded in our dialer.  They offer a test that can be run but it doesn't continuously monitor, as far as I know... I will definitely check that out tho, to see if there is any data we can pull from there!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Andrew (+1!) you should check the quality of the connection, more than the type/topology. That could be quite pointless since (i) topology can vary **a lot** and (ii) **several** other factors can affect the connection, apart from the used bearer.

That said, `QNetworkConfiguration` is still the answer to the bearer checking question but via the [`QNetworkConfigurationManager`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkconfigurationmanager.html) class. Indeed, a valid `QNetworkConfiguration` **can** be available to you even if the corresponding (wired or not wired) connection is **not** available, at the moment.

You should code something like this:

```
QNetworkConfiguration cfg;    
QNetworkConfigurationManager ncm;
auto nc = ncm.allConfigurations(QNetworkConfiguration::Active);   //ACTIVE ONES

for (auto &x : nc)
{
    if (x.bearerType() == QNetworkConfiguration::BearerEthernet)
    {
        cfg = x;
        // other stuff that pleases you
    }
}
```

Mind that the results are somewhat *frozen* to the time the `QNetworkConfigurationManager` was created. To update the list, before skimming it, you can call the (time consuming) `updateConfigurations()`.

Finally, by exploiting the `configurationChanged(const QNetworkConfiguration & config)` signal, you can track down status changes for your LAN connection.

Comment: This is good!  We were discussing the possibility of them tricking it by plugging in then unplugging.  The configurationChanged tho.. nice touch!  And yeah, we are currently collecting pings.. but maybe we should just do more there: packet loss, jitter, etc.  The QNetworkConfiguration seemed to work except when someone only uses the LAC to connect, in which case there would be no Ethernet (even when hard-wired)... if I understand correctly... not the coder, just developer :)  Sorry, would +1 you, too but I just don't have the power

Comment: In such a particular case, what is the content of the "nc" variable? At least you have a "QNetworkConfiguration::BearerUnknown" in the Bearer enumeration. :D

Comment: If I follow this correctly :) mine (when connected with Ethernet & WiFi) shows and entry for Ethernet, Wifi, and Local Area Connection  (even though I never setup or used the LAC).  When I unplug the Ethernet, I just show an entry for WiFi and LAC.  My coder, who only uses LAC, shows just an LAC entry.  So if we were to just look for the Ethernet entry, he would be locked out, even though he is hard-wired.

Comment: Hence, this code returns always a configuration for the LAC. With which bearer from this list: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkconfiguration.html#BearerType-enum ?

Comment: Ahhh.. for me, it is Unknown.  I'm not sure what it shows for the coder... I would assume (hope?) that if it was distinguishable, he would have caught it...

Comment: I see. Going that way seems a bit too tricky. You can combine the "unknown" result with some other checks but that would be pointless since (as we repeated so many times) you should point to other parameters to monitor the connection. Good luck! :)